# How to code that bot will make a temp instant invite?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I'm trying to make that my bot will create a temp instant invite for a guild that it's currently in. Is it possible? (This bot will be public, so it will be in a lot of guilds)
If so, I'm asking for help <3
(Sorry, if this is easy to code. I'm still learning js ;D)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`GuildChannel.createInvite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite). Here's an example:

```
// ASSUMPTIONS:
// message is the message that triggered the command
// the channel of the invite will be the channel where the message has been sent

async function replyWithInvite(message) {
  let invite = await message.channel.createInvite(
  {
    maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000, // maximum time for the invite, in milliseconds
    maxUses: 1 // maximum times it can be used
  },
  `Requested with command by ${message.author.tag}`
)
.catch(console.log);

  message.reply(invite ? `Here's your invite: ${invite}` : "There has been an error during the creation of the invite.");
}
```

You can change the channel by maybe adding an argument. Please note that this will work only if the bot has the permission to create invites.

Comment: Thank you very much. And again, I'm really sorry, becasue now it looks really simple, but I'm still learning so, thank you for your help <3

Comment: Don't worry :) I suggest you to use the search bar in the [docs website](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome): it can help you find quickly the methods you need ;)